# How to select dataframe in R filter max( ) min( ) and conditional value?

Tags: r

I have this little fragment of a dataframe:

| A | B | C | D | E |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 10 | .B. | 41.32 | 5.00e-02 | 28 |
| 10 | .C. | 41.26 | 5.08e-02 | 28 |
| 10 | .X. | 42.43 | 2.13e-01 | 36 |
| 9 | .A. | 41.07 | 5.23e-02 | 28 |
| 9 | .A. | 41.07 | 5.28e-02 | 28 |
| 8 | .X. | 38.97 | 8.13e-02 | 28 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |

```
res<-data.frame(year = c(10L,10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L), c.col = c("B","C", "A", "A", "A", "X"), chisq = c(41.32,41.26, 42.43, 41.07, 41.08, 38.97), p.value = c(5.00e-02,5.08e-02, 2.13e-01, 5.23e-02, 5.28e-02, 8.13e-02),  df = c(26,28, 36,28, 28, 28))

#this filter is not working, what is the correct way to do it?
res %>%  dplyr::group_by(year) %>% dplyr::filter(res$year==10 & min(p.value) & max(df))
```

Expected output:

| A | B | C | D | E |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | .X. | 42.43 | 2.13e-01 | 36 |

Comment: It's not at all clear what you're trying to do.  Your code snippet doesn't match the tables you provided.  What do you want if the minimum p.value and maximum df are in different rows for a given year?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to conditionally select the row with the `min` and `max`, you can use the following code:

```
res %>%  
  dplyr::group_by(year) %>% 
  dplyr::filter(year==10 & p.value == min(p.value) & df == max(df))
```

Please note that in your example `res`, there is no row with the `min` & `max` value.